# Kinect 2 Inconsistent FloorClipPlane reading

Tags: c#, kinect, tracking

I have successfully implemented the floor clip plane to measure the distance of left foot to the floor, which is fairly accurate. The problem I have is that as I move away from the camera (i.e. left foot Z axis is increased), the foot distance to the floor changes (increases).

Note: The floor itself is not tilted nor the Kinect stand.

I tested it with Kinect 1 and had the same result. The subject's head height (Y axis) also changes value as I move away or get closer to the camera. It does not matter of the camera is tilted or line of sight. the D value in the FloorClipPlane equation shows a constant number during the test.

```
                    A = bodyFrame.FloorClipPlane.X;
                    B = bodyFrame.FloorClipPlane.Y;
                    C = bodyFrame.FloorClipPlane.Z;
                    D = bodyFrame.FloorClipPlane.W;


        distanceLeftFoot = A * leftFootPosX + B * leftFootPosY + C * leftFootPosZ + D;
```

Just to let you know, I have coordinate mapping between depth and colour. Not sure if that has anything to do with the issue.

Comment: `code double divisor = Math.Sqrt(leftFootPosX * leftFootPosX + leftFootPosY * leftFootPosY + leftFootPosZ * leftFootPosZ);
            float test=Convert.ToSingle(divisor);
            distanceLeftFoot = (A * leftFootPosX + B * leftFootPosY + C * leftFootPosZ + D)/ test;`

I forgot to mention this as well

Answer (score 2):

The FloorClipPlane is expressed in hessian normal form - as explained [in the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowspreview.kinect.bodyframe.floorclipplane.aspx). Specifically, your A, B, and C values compromise the unit vector from camera origin (center of the Kinect) to floor plane such that it produces a perpendicular intersection with the floor plane. D is the magnitude of that vector (distance from camera origin to floor plane).

Even if you think the floor is flat and the Kinect is parallel to the ground, you have a perspective warping problem which means the body location (measured in depth space) is going to change as you come closer and further.

To fix this you need to provide as input both your 3D coordinate values and the floor plane, which will then give you back what you want, a measured distance from floor plane to joint:

[image: 1]

```
// j is your joint - left foot or any other joint
float x = j.Position.X;
float y = j.Position.Y;
float z = j.Position.Z;
float distance = (Math.Abs((x * floorPlane.X) + (y * floorPlane.Y) + (z * floorPlane.Z) + floorPlane.W))/((float)Math.Sqrt((Math.Pow(floorPlane.X,2)) + (Math.Pow(floorPlane.Y, 2)) + (Math.Pow(floorPlane.Z, 2))));
```

I hope this helps you. Can't elaborate further what influence your mapping from depth to color might be doing here without seeing what you are specifically doing